Angular material mat-drawer-content margin-right behavior
1 - There is a CSS code have been written in ts file to apply when browser size is being changed. but if you check console while changing browser size ( width) can be seen sometime apply below CSS. but sometime instead of this CSS
  @HostListener('window:resize', ['$event'])
  onResize(): void {
    if (this.detailsPanel && this.detailsPanel.opened) {
      this.mainGridContent.getElementRef().nativeElement.style.marginRight = 'calc(30% + var(--granite-spacing-8))';
    }
  }


(I suspect this is happening because executing the CSS inside the HostListener may take some time. If the CSS value is not received from the TypeScript file within a short period, mat-drawer-content might apply a default CSS value.)
Does anyone have an idea about this behavior? What approach should be taken to fix it?
